# Create stored procedure phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL says I have syntax error near '' at line 3. Please help

My objective is to calculate the sum of medications' prices

Here is my SQL code from phpmyadmin:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spMEDICATION_FEE(IN PatientID CHAR(9))

BEGIN

DECLARE Sum2 INT;
DECLARE Sum3 INT;

SET Sum2 = (
    SELECT SUM(MPRICE)
    FROM USES_EXAM INNER JOIN MEDICATION ON USES_EXAM.MID = MEDICATION.MID
    WHERE PID_OUT = PatientID);

SET Sum3 = (
    SELECT SUM(MPRICE)
    FROM USES_TREAT INNER JOIN MEDICATION ON USES_TREAT.MID = MEDICATION.MID
    WHERE PID_IN = PatientID);

IF Sum2 IS NULL THEN
    SET Sum2 = 0;

IF Sum3 IS NULL THEN
    SET Sum3 = 0;

SELECT Sum2+ Sum3 AS 'Total fee';

END
```

Comment: If;s must have end ifs and did you set delimiters?

Comment: Yep, didn't work

Comment: Syntaxs fine for me(with corrections) what do you mean by didn't work?

Comment: Here is the error:
https://ibb.co/gWJyJc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL tab of phpymadmin to run this query, you should define a delimiter instead of `;`. For example, try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

paste your create procedure code here

$$
```

Comment: What is the error now ? And can you take a screenshot of the input and error ?

Comment: The space between DELIMITER and $$ is not optional.

Comment: Ok, why am I so blind. Thank you